# How to solve ./configure missing package

Tags: build, dependencies, configure, inkscape

I would like to build Inkscape. I already solved some missing packages but the journey is not finished yet...

This time it's bdw-gc that is missing:

```
checking for IMAGEMAGICK... no
checking for INKSCAPE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (bdw-gc      >= 7.1
                  cairo       >= 1.10
                  cairomm-1.0 >= 1.9.8
                  glib-2.0    >= 2.28
                  glibmm-2.4  >= 2.28
                  giomm-2.4
                  gsl
                  gthread-2.0 >= 2.0
                  libpng      >= 1.2
                  libxml-2.0  >= 2.6.11
                  libxslt     >= 1.0.15
                  pango       >= 1.24
                  pangoft2    >= 1.24
                  sigc++-2.0  >= 2.0.12
                  ) were not met:

No package 'bdw-gc' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

So I downloaded `bdwgc-master` solve some issues then installed it:

```
$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/bdwgc-master'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/bdwgc-master'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libgc.la libcord.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgc.dll.a /usr/local/lib/libgc.dll.a
libtool: install: base_file=`basename libgc.la`
libtool: install:  dlpath=`/bin/sh 2>&1 -c '. .libs/'libgc.la'i; echo cyggc-1.dll'`
libtool: install:  dldir=/usr/local/lib/`dirname ../bin/cyggc-1.dll`
libtool: install:  test -d /usr/local/lib/../bin || mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/../bin
libtool: install:  /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cyggc-1.dll /usr/local/lib/../bin/cyggc-1.dll
libtool: install:  chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/../bin/cyggc-1.dll
libtool: install:  if test -n '' && test -n 'strip --strip-unneeded'; then eval 'strip --strip-unneeded /usr/local/lib/../bin/cyggc-1.dll' || exit 0; fi
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgc.lai /usr/local/lib/libgc.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcord.dll.a /usr/local/lib/libcord.dll.a
libtool: install: base_file=`basename libcord.la`
libtool: install:  dlpath=`/bin/sh 2>&1 -c '. .libs/'libcord.la'i; echo cygcord-1.dll'`
libtool: install:  dldir=/usr/local/lib/`dirname ../bin/cygcord-1.dll`
libtool: install:  test -d /usr/local/lib/../bin || mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/../bin
libtool: install:  /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cygcord-1.dll /usr/local/lib/../bin/cygcord-1.dll
libtool: install:  chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/../bin/cygcord-1.dll
libtool: install:  if test -n '' && test -n 'strip --strip-unneeded'; then eval 'strip --strip-unneeded /usr/local/lib/../bin/cygcord-1.dll' || exit 0; fi
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcord.lai /usr/local/lib/libcord.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgc.a /usr/local/lib/libgc.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libgc.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libgc.a
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcord.a /usr/local/lib/libcord.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libcord.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libcord.a
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gc'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 AUTHORS README.md doc/README.DGUX386 doc/README.Mac doc/README.OS2 doc/README.amiga doc/README.arm.cross doc/README.autoconf doc/README.cmake doc/README.cords doc/README.darwin doc/README.environment doc/README.ews4800 doc/README.hp doc/README.linux doc/README.macros doc/README.rs6000 doc/README.sgi doc/README.solaris2 doc/README.symbian doc/README.uts doc/README.win32 doc/README.win64 doc/debugging.html doc/finalization.html doc/gc.man doc/gcdescr.html doc/gcinterface.html doc/leak.html doc/overview.html doc/porting.html doc/scale.html doc/simple_example.html doc/tree.html '/usr/local/share/gc'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/extra/gc.h '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bdw-gc.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/gc'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/gc.h include/gc_allocator.h include/gc_backptr.h include/gc_config_macros.h include/gc_disclaim.h include/gc_gcj.h include/gc_inline.h include/gc_mark.h include/gc_pthread_redirects.h include/gc_tiny_fl.h include/gc_typed.h include/gc_version.h include/javaxfc.h include/leak_detector.h include/weakpointer.h include/cord.h include/cord_pos.h include/ec.h '/usr/local/include/gc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/bdwgc-master'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/bdwgc-master'
```

So I have `bdw-gc` installed in my system, but I still get the error. This kind of problem happen to me very often. I would like to lean how to solve them or at least how to investigate.

I noticed bwdgc was installed on `/usr/local/`. I also checked that the `inkscape` `./configure` has the right prefix:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep usr
                          [/usr/local]
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
```

So I am a bit lost with this. What's the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to install gc library:
http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gc_source/